# Sign out a specific lync user using lync sdk

Tags: c#, lync, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

as you might know lync support multi users to be logged in same time, this cause a problems to our application so we want to force the first user to log out once a second user logged in.

Is there a way to sign out a specific lync user using lync sdk (client sdk or server sdk)? I can't find anything in lync sdk or lync server sdk or event on the web.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg195756.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync-online-administration-and-management.aspx Hope these posts will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each logged in user in Lync is an endpoint. You can use the [`Set-CsRegistrarConfiguration`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398764.aspx) powershell command to change the `MaxEndpointsPerUser` setting. Setting it to 1 disallows users to create more than a single endpoint.

> Lync Server lets you set the maximum number of endpoints to any integer value between 1 and 64, inclusive. The default value is 8.

Comment: Thanks Willem this is exactly what we was looking for :)